# How do I support user-configurable shortcuts in GTK+ menus?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

Using `GtkUIManager`, it's easy to specify accelerators for `GtkAction`s. However, some users inevitably want different accelerators, or want accelerators for actions that I don't think see enough usage to warrant them.

`GtkAccelMap` looks like what I need, but the documentation suggests that it's more low-level than required, and that `GtkUIManager` should be used. It looks like I could support a fixed-location `.ui` file containing only `<accelerator>` entries, but this isn't explicitly suggested anywhere I can find, and I don't know of other applications that do this.

What is the suggested/approved way to support user customisation of accelerators for menu actions?